# Modified or Updated Timestamp in Kubernetes Secrets

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, okd

In Kubernetes secrets I can only retrieve creation timestamp

```
metadata:
  creationTimestamp:
```

However I don't find a way to check modified/updated timestamp

Is this a lacking feature or I am not able to find it ?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, while Kubernetes metadata usually includes creationTimestamp, there would not be anything tracking previous or last edition timestamp. For deployments, you could track changes using their replicasets. Or querying etcd directly, you may find about previous revisions for any object, that were not yet removed by etcd compactions.

One reliable way to keep track of these would be to enable [Kubernetes audit logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/). Then you may track who creates, updates or deletes objects.

If you already use EFK or similar logging stack, you should be able to store audit logs alongside your cluster logs -- better use a distinct index pattern. Note there can be a huge volume of logs to keep: another way to store it would be to export those logs to s3, then use something like Athena or Hive querying those data.